# VS Code editor error vs code editor "an error occurred while restoring view:imagePreview.previewEditor"

Tags: visual-studio-code

Couldn't load the image in Live Server and showing an error "**an error occurred while restoring view:imagePreview.previewEditor**". I have placed the image in same folder and name was also correct.
The following is the CSS code.

```
    body{
     font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
     background-color: black;
    }
    #container{
     width: 1000px;
     height: 550px;
     background-image: url(bgi.jpg);
     margin:20px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes problem resolved. a simple restart of VS Code editor could get rid off the issue..